# How to aggregage default dict data

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I have a list of dictionaries as follow:

```
result = {
    "resultset": [
        {"name": "DOG", "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"), "current_value": 124},
        {"name": "DOG", "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"), "current_value": 14},
        {"name": "DOG", "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"), "current_value": 1},
        {"name": "CAT", "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"), "current_value": 24},
        {"name": "CAT", "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"), "current_value": 4},
    ]
}
```

Now i want to actually do 2 things, basically do an aggrgation where i get:

1. A list of current_values []
2. An average of the threshold value

so in the end I wanna see :

```
{
'DOG': {'current_values': [124,14,1], 'threshold': the average of threshold},
'CAT': {'current_values': [24,4] , 'threshold': the average of threshold}
}
```

I got half of it working where i can get the list of current_values but not the whole using the default dict where i can do something like

```
all_animals  = defaultdict(list)
     for i in result['resultset']:                
           all_animals[i['name']].append(float(i['current_value']))
```

Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece of cake with `defaultdict` and `statistics`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from collections import defaultdict
import statistics

result = {
    "resultset": [
        {
            "name": "DOG",
            "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"),
            "current_value": 124,
        },
        {
            "name": "DOG",
            "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"),
            "current_value": 14,
        },
        {
            "name": "DOG",
            "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"),
            "current_value": 1,
        },
        {
            "name": "CAT",
            "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"),
            "current_value": 24,
        },
        {
            "name": "CAT",
            "threshold": Decimal("1.45600000"),
            "current_value": 4,
        },
    ]
}

current_values_by_name = defaultdict(list)
thresholds_by_name = defaultdict(list)
for x in result["resultset"]:
    current_values_by_name[x["name"]].append(x["current_value"])
    thresholds_by_name[x["name"]].append(x["threshold"])

aggregate_result = {
    name: {
        "current_values": current_values_by_name[name],
        "threshold": statistics.mean(thresholds_by_name[name]),
    }
    for name in current_values_by_name
}

print(aggregate_result)
```

outputs

```
{
    "DOG": {
        "current_values": [124, 14, 1],
        "threshold": Decimal("1.456"),
    },
    "CAT": {
        "current_values": [24, 4],
        "threshold": Decimal("1.456"),
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you help me understand the aggregate_result, or if you can write it with a simple to understand syntax, please

Comment: It's simply a dictionary comprehension. You could rewrite it as `aggregate_result = {}; for name in current_values_by_name: aggregate_result[name] = {"current...`